# CDG - Is 3Hour enough for non-connecting to land at T1, Followed next T2F

Tags: indian-citizens, cdg, air-france

I am curious to know, now in 2023, how much time it takes to exit completely, passports stamped, take luggage and Check-in next flight at Terminal-T2F. My flights are next month - March2023, it's not connecting flights, but two separate flights / Itinaries. I have almost a 3 hour window between these flights. I will arrive at Terminal-T1 and next flight starts at T2F.

I am an Indian Citizen with EU residency.

Comment: I can not predict how long you will need, but I have suffered a three hour late arrival on CDG and if you have that on a self connection you will have to buy new tickets for all following flights.

Comment: thanks @Willeke, how much it took for customs and baggage collections !

Comment: I did not need to go through  bagage collections and customs as my flights were on one ticket.

Comment: Where are you arriving from/departing to? Do you have status with either airline?

Comment: Arriving at CDG-Terminal T1, departing to Spain from CDG Terminal T2F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Landed on time or more or less 5-10mins (6PM Evening, Thursday) at CDG Terminal-1, 30mins to cover Immigration and customs, 30mins Baggage pickup and 15 mins to exit Terminal 1, CDG-VAL to Terminal 2 - Walked towards Zone 4 - Took around 40mins to reach, Long walk.

With all these timings, I could have taken the 2nd flight, but opted out of it, since I have three big luggages, cannot take the risk of airline losing them within 3 hours of time to report and follow upon it. Maybe if I had only hand-luggage, I would have taken it.

Comment: 40 minutes from CDGVAL to T2F? You probably didn’t take the shortest path, it’s 500 meters, it should take 10 minutes.

Comment: From Terminal1 - CDGVAL train time to almost end of terminal 2F.. its long walk .. didnt know there was any other shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

This is very difficult to predict and depends on a lot of factors. If things go  well 3 hours should be ok, but it's risky with not a lot of room for errors or mishaps. Personally, I would not book this unless the connecting flight is cheap and easy to change.

I've flown through CDG a few times in the last few months and the experience was all over the place. On one international to Schengen connection, the line at immigration was absolutely horrific and passengers were panicking and missing fligghts. On other occasions it was quick and painless.